# 8788v2 MageReport not showing as patched

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-8788v2

Just a quick question. I have patched a site that is on 1.9.2.4 and it has been upgraded. But on Mage Report it is not showing as patched, despite it showing it in the applied patches file.

In their notes it says that it looks for `/js/mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js` should contain "fustyFlowFactory" But I have noticed that the folder and file is missing, and also I have looked on Magento and downloaded that version and its not listed in there. Would adding the file solve my issue.

Information is on here: https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/magento-patch-supee-8788-release-1-9-3/

Comment: If it is in the applied patches file, but _not_ on your filesystem, than apparently your patch did not succeed (or the file was later removed by someone else / another process). Why not try to add this file instead of asking here? Also, did you check that the .swf files were removed?

Comment: the swf files where removed and the patch was applied successfully. I could try adding the file. I just wanted to make sure.